# What's the difference between "Spain's fastfood consumption" and "the consumption of fastfood in Spain"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, possessives

I am describing a chart in that chart 22% of Spanish people consumed fast food. Are the two sentences below correct?

Is there a difference between these sentences in meaning?

1. Spain's fast food consumption was 22% in 2002
2. The consumption of fast food in Spain was 22% in 2002

The former seems natural to me with possessive. Is it similar to "The people who consumed fastfood was 22% in 2002 in Spain"? This sentence seems ok to me. Is there a difference in meaning between sentence one and this?

Comment: What do you think? Is there any reason a possessive is wrong here? The boy's father was waiting in the car. The father of the boy was waiting in the car. Any difference?

Comment: Thx. The former seems natural to me with possessive. Is it similar to ( The people who consumed fastfood was 22% in 2002 in Spain) this sentence seems ok to me . Is there a difference in meaning between sentence one and this?

Comment: I gave you another example.

Comment: I was referring to your sentence by writing "The former seems natural to me with possessive"

Comment: I think I misunderstood you when editing the question. Please edit so that your thoughts on the two sentences you're asking about are in the question itself.

Comment: father of the boy=boy's father. Both can be used. But when we can use a possessive, we generally do.

Comment: Thx that means both are fine. Someone edited my main post please look at it.

Comment: _The people who consumed fastfood was 22% in 2002 in Spain_ is not a valid sentence. People can't be a percentage. **The proportion of people in Spain who consumed fast food (two words) in 2002 was 22%.**

Comment: "Spain's fast food consumption was 22% in 2002". This is sentence one. I think It is similar in meaning to your sentence

Comment: Neither sentence makes any sense.  It is unclear what you are trying to say.

Comment: 'Fast food' is two words.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any significant difference between your two examples, any more than there is a difference between "*my father's son*" and "*the son of my father*". Spain's fast food consumption means the fast food consumed by Spain.

On a separate issue, I find the both statements to be unclear. When you quote a percentage it must be clear to the reader what it represents. What is the numerator and denominator used in calculating this rate. Does it mean that 22% of all food eaten is 'fast' food? Is that by volume of food? Or are you counting meals? Do you mean 22% of Spanish people eat fast food? Grammatically, either statement is fine; but you need to consider whether it makes any logical or statistical sense.

Your suggested alternative sounds like it is a percentage of *people*. Assuming that is correct, I would say:

- In Spain, 22% of people consumed fast food in 2002.

Comment: Exactly. Neither of OP’s versions can be recommended because they are far too ambiguous. They could even mean something like, out of all the fast food eaten in Europe, Spain’s consumption constitutes 22%.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the first main post . I hope it is clear now

Comment: @Rafeq It is clearer, and I still believe my suggested sentence is the best way to express that.